# no cambia el color de la imagen con el hover en css y html

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo este ejercicio de `css` y `html`.

Estoy replicando esta pagina web como se ve en la siguiente imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando pongo el cursor sobre los cuadros estos muestran un texto y cambia de color como se ve en el circulo rojo.

Y aquí está mi replica en `css` y `html` como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el circulo grande de la izquierda pongo el cursor y no cambia nada. En el circulo de la derecha, en la linea de `css` está el `hover` pero no cambia nada. Ese es el problema, no funciona el `hover`.

Traté de encontrar varias soluiones y ninguna funciona. Necesito su ayuda en que este `hover` cambie el color de la imagen.

Este es el link de la pagina original: https://vivelaconco.com/gdl/ca.html

Y este es mi código:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(image/speakersbg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 241px;
  background: url("image/banner-inner2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "BebasNeue";
  color: white;
}

#logotipo-1 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

#logotipo-1 img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 52px;
}

#logotipo-1 h3 {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(50, 51, 51, .8);
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#menu-lista {
  max-width: 440px;
  float: right;
  background: transparent;
  padding-right: 255px;
  padding-top: 46px;
}

#lista-2 {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#lista-2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  padding: 28px 20px;
}

.menu-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  width: 190px;
  height: 170px;
}

#lista-2 li:hover .menu-vertical {
  display: block;
}

.menu-vertical {
  background-color: rgb(11, 40, 204);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-vertical li {
  height: 35px;
}

.menu-vertical .fila-vertical {
  height: 35px;
  width: 190px;
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

.menu-vertical li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu-vertical li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(61, 108, 207);
}

#comprar-tickets {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: -660px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ec398b;
}

#comprar-tickets h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 51px;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ec398b;
  transition: all 400ms;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar:hover {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#contenedor {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-top: 162px;
}

.cuadros {
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 262px;
  border: solid 14px #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  /*
        background-image: url(../3-ejercicio/image/amatesaurius.png);
        background-size: cover;
        */
}

#cuadros {
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 262px;
  border: solid 14px #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  /*
        background-image: url(../3-ejercicio/image/amatesaurius.png);
        background-size: cover;
        */
}

.image img {
  width: 264px;
  height: 286px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  background: none;
}

.image img:hover {
  background: solid #1b273d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>3 ejercicio desde 0</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="nav-bar">

    <div class="barra">

      <div id="logotipo-1">
        <span class="logo-1">
                        <img src="image/con-co.png" alt="concomics">
                    </span>
        <h3>vive la conco</h3>
      </div>

      <nav id="menu-lista">
        <!-- ESTO MUEVE EL MENU DE IZQ. A DER. -->

        <ul id="lista-2">
          <li><a href="#">INVITADOS. </a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">CONCURSOS. </a>
            <ul class="menu-vertical">
              <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
              <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
              <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
              <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ALLEY'S. </a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">GAMING. </a>
            <ul class="menu-vertical">
              <li><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">INFO GENERAL. </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div id="comprar-tickets">
        <div id="comprar">
          <h3>CONTENIDO</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="contenedor">

    <article class="cuadros">

      <div class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/amatesaurius.png" alt="concomics">
      </div>

    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">

      <span class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/michdahaka.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">
      <span class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/rizel.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">
      <span class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/darkittie.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">
      <span class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/pikacos.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">
      <span class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/dalia-cos.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">
      <span class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/flaiveth.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">
      <span class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/tuti.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">
      <span class="image">
        <img src="../3-ejercicio/image/pretty.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

    <article class="cuadros">
      <span class="image">
         <img src="" alt="concomics">
      </span>
    </article>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `background: solid #1b273d;` no es valido, reemplázalo por `background-color: #1b273d;`